# Brouwers Fixed Point Theorem Proof using Winding Numbers

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

[image: mp]

Hi. I've been reading Visual Complex Analysis and have been trying to prove Brouwer's Fixed Point theorem on the unit disc as set out in one of the exercises, using winding numbers/Rouche's Theorem. Part 1 I have been able to show, but I am having trouble with proving (or intuitively grassing) part 2 so I was wondering if anyone could help out with this part. Any help welcome! 
Thank you.

Note: $v[m(C), 0]$ refers to the winding number of $m(c)$ around $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image of $C_0$ (under the $g(z)-z$ map) is a nonzero point; for small $r$, the image of $C_r$ must be a small loop in the neighborhood of that point, so it cannot wind around the origin. As $r$ increases, the loop grows bigger, but it can never cross the origin (because $g(z)-z$ is never zero), so the winding number can never change.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply - makes sense now! For the first part I originally used the dog walking lemma (Rouche's Theorem) but then realised its a non-strict inequality so this cannot be applied. Would you have a way of explaining the 'intuitive' paragraph Newham writes to understand part 1?

Comment: @Daniele1234 Taking $z$ on the unit circle, Newham is imagining drawing a vector from $z$ to the origin (that's the $-z$ vector) and another vector from $z$ to $g(z)$ (that's the $m(z)$ vector). Since $g(z)$ must land within the unit disk, the angle between the two vectors must be acute (a right angle from $z$ would already bring us tangent to the disk and not back inside). Now imagine the $-z$ vector and the $m(z)$ vector winding together; in order for the angle to stay acute always, they must wind the same number of times.

Comment: thank you all understood now - much appreciated!